# Shortcode is displaying the wrong post_title

Tags: custom-post-types

I have got a shortcode that displays a custom post type, via a `foreach`. The shortcode has been used in the standard post type. I have used `the_title();` in the shortcode. `the_title();` outputs the post_title of the standard post type (which the shortcode is in), rather than `the_title();` of the custom post type. My code:

```
function faq_register_shortcode()  {  
  add_shortcode( 'display_faqs', 'mp_faq_shortcode' );  
}  
function mp_faq_shortcode() {    
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'faq_type_mp', 'numberposts' => 3, 'post_status' => 'any', 'post_parent' => null );   
  $attachments = get_posts( $args );  
  if ($attachments) {   
    foreach ( $attachments as $post ) {  
                the_title();  
        the_content();  
    }  
  } 
}
```

So for example, if the standard post type (which the shortcode is in), had a `post_title` of 'this is the standard post type', this is what is outputted in the shortcode. I want to display the  `post_title` which belongs to the custom post type, NOT the standard post (which the shortcode is in).

What have I done wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `setup_postdata($post);` inside your loop:

```
    foreach ( $attachments as $post ) {  
setup_postdata($post);
                the_title();  
        the_content();  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks again! I also need to put `$post;` right at the start of the second function. I just need to find out why now (very much a newbie).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you'll need to use `setup_postdata($post);` inside of your foreach loop. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata

Comment: @mattnewbie - Then why have you marked the other answer with the same solution as the answer if it is not correct? :/

Answer (score 0):

Both [`the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) and [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) are template tags and the operate inside the Loop based on the `global` variable `$post` which is setup by [`setup_postdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) or by [`the_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post) ([which runs `setup_postdata`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/query.php#L2846)). What is happening is that those tags are using whatever values were last shoved into the `global $post` variable. You can run [`setup_postdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) in your function as already suggested or do something like:

```
foreach ( $attachments as $post ) {  
    echo apply_filters('the_title',$post->post_title));  
    echo apply_filters('the_content',$post->post_content));  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**THE ANSWER**

This is the working code

```
function faq_register_shortcode()  {  
  /* register the [display_faqs] shortcode */  
  add_shortcode( 'display_faqs', 'mp_faq_shortcode' );  
}    
function mp_faq_shortcode() {   
  global $post;  
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'faq_type_mp', 'numberposts' => 3, 'post_status' => 'any', 'post_parent' => null );   
  $attachments = get_posts( $args );    
  if ($attachments) {  
    foreach ( $attachments as $post ) {   
      setup_postdata($post);  
      the_title();  
      the_content();  
    }    
  }   
}
```

Based on this codex page (someone linked to) https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata . Sorry I can't explain it further, because I don't currently understand why it works.

Comment: Can you please explain this answer.

Comment: I'd love to be able to explain the answer, but I don't understand it myself. I visited  the `setup_postdata($post);` codex page someone linked to & just copied it.  Here is the codex page https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata  I will post the full working code above! Once , I've figured out why that works I'll get back to you.

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the WYSIWYG post editor-- especially the button that looks like `{}`.